# Armazenar dados da requisição app.post nodejs

Tags: node.js, variáveis, post, app

Fala galera, gostaria de saber como posso utilizar os dados recebidos da pagina para utilizar fora do app.post?

```js
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
var Readline = SerialPort.parsers.Readline;
var methodOverride = require('method-override');


//faz requerimento dos modulos
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
const express = require('express');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');
const http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

//cria servidor
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo.listen(server);

//starta servidor na porta 3000
server.listen(3000, () => {
 console.log('Servidor Online na porta 3000');
});

//define um diretorio commo public para acesso as propriedades
app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), {
 maxAge: '1d'
 }));

// retorna index quano recebe requição
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
 app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), {
  maxAge: '1d'
  }));
});

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true });
app.route('/signup');
app.post( '/signup', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
 var portCOM = req.body.portCOM;
 var bauRATE = req.body.bauRATE;
 res.json(
  { 
      message: 'signup success',
   portCOM : portCOM,
   bauRATE : bauRATE,
  }
 );
});

app.get(function(req,res){
 res.json({message: 'get request from signup'});
});

// configurações da comunicação serial
port = new SerialPort(portCOM, {
 baudRate: 9600,
    dataBits: 8,
    paridade: 'nenhum' ,
    stopBits: 1,
    flowControl: false ,
    parser: new SerialPort.parsers.Readline('\r')  
});

//define um limite para acionar um evento
const ByteLength = require('@serialport/parser-byte-length');
const parser = port.pipe(new ByteLength({length: 4}));

//EXIBE OS LOG NO TERMINAL, INFORMAÇOES VINDA DO ARDUINO
port.open(function()
{
 console.log('Porta aberta');
});

var ModbusTCP = "";
parser.on('data', function (data)
{  
  ModbusTCP = data.toString();
  ModbusTCP = ModbusTCP.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,""); 
  var infLeng = ModbusTCP.length;  
  
  console.log('tamanho do envio:',infLeng);
  console.log('Valor Hexadeciaml: ' + ModbusTCP);
});
```

Comment: Não basta apenas chamar uma função passando o req? Ou talvez o que você queira seja capturar e tratar esses argumentos antes de chegar no app.post com um middleware? Pode descrever o que você está tentando fazer?

Comment: estou passando alguns parâmetros do lado do cliente para conectar a uma porta serial, então preciso pegar estes parâmetros que estão armazenados dentro do app.post e trata-los fora do app.post

Comment: quando tento utilizar a variavel portCOM fora do app.post tenho o retorno portCOM is not defined.

Comment: Ainda não estou entendendo qual é a dificuldade. Não basta enviar `portCOM` ou `res` como parâmetro para outra função? Você pode editar a sua pergunta, postando o código completo, incluindo a parte que dá erro?

Comment: postei o código completo, na parte que configuro a conexão com a porta COM eu não consigo utilizar a variável.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao que dá para perceber, `portCOM` é utilizado em `SerialPort`, mas `SerialPort` não está sendo chamado através de um middleware, ele está direto na raiz do script, o que significa que ele será executado apenas uma vez quando o servidor for iniciado, antes mesmo do usuário enviar o valor de `portCOM`.

Para executar `SerialPort` apenas quando a reaquisição for enviada para a rota `signup`, você precisa colocar ou chamar o código dentro da função de callback da rota:

```
app.post('/signup', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
    const portCOM = req.body.portCOM;
    const bauRATE = req.body.bauRATE;

    criarPorta(portCOM);

    res.json({
        message: 'signup success',
        portCOM: portCOM,
        bauRATE: bauRATE,
    });
});

function criarPorta(portCOM) {
    port = new SerialPort(portCOM, {
        baudRate: 9600,
        dataBits: 8,
        paridade: 'nenhum',
        stopBits: 1,
        flowControl: false,
        parser: new SerialPort.parsers.Readline('\r')
    });

    // .
    // .
    // .
    // Restante do código
}
```

Ou então usar o código como middleware:

```
app.post('/signup', urlencodedParser, criarPorta, function (req, res) {
    const portCOM = req.body.portCOM;
    const bauRATE = req.body.bauRATE;

    res.json({
        message: 'signup success',
        portCOM: portCOM,
        bauRATE: bauRATE,
    });
});

function criarPorta(req, res, next) {
    const portCOM = req.body.portCOM;

    port = new SerialPort(portCOM, {
        baudRate: 9600,
        dataBits: 8,
        paridade: 'nenhum',
        stopBits: 1,
        flowControl: false,
        parser: new SerialPort.parsers.Readline('\r')
    });

    // .
    // .
    // .
    // Restante do código

    next();
}
```

Comment: showww muito obrigado, eu tinha feito diferente, havia colocado dentro do  middleware principal app.post e funcionou, mas o teu método é o correto e mais estável.

Comment: A estabilidade é a mesma, só é um pouco mais organizado. Vou dar uma dica que eu acabei não deixando na resposta: você pode usar o middleware `urlencodedParser` antes da declaração das rotas, dessa forma você não precisa declara-lo manualmente em todas as rotas que você criar. Apenas coloque `app.use(urlencodedParser)` acima da declaração das rotas, e o parse do corpo das requisições será feito da mesma forma.